# Find the reversal transactions in my table

Tags: sql

I have a table data like the bellow

```
Date       Amount  
01022017   300
01052017   -300
03042016   200
06112016   400
05042016   -200
30012016   150
```

I need only the list like below (the negatives are reversals happen to those transactions).

My expected result like

```
Date       Amount  
06112016   400
30012016   150
```

I need to avoid the reversal transactions. But here in my table I don't have any reference column to indicate the transaction as reversal or normal transaction.

Comment: Same negative amount means reversal? Couldn't there be a transaction with a reversal and then another one without with the same amount? How would you know which transaction to leave?

Comment: I need to avoid same amount with negative ... but the reversal may happen in any day after the original transaction done . Here in my case the reversal amount is same as transaction amount but it will have negative sign

Comment: That is why I have given the sample result set which I am expecting .

Comment: In my case I need to avoid 300 and 200 transactions ... Because those are reversals

Comment: If your sample table have 1 more row, e.g `02022017   300`, Then the `01052017   -300` will be reversal transactions for `02022017   300` or `01022017    300`? Which logic indicate that?

Comment: You should have a reference that say which pair of rows is `transactions - reversal transactions`. Only count on `x money vs -x money` is not logic, and we can't work with that to create a query.

Comment: Is it possible for today's transaction to get reversed on tomorrow?

Comment: @sukanthbejugam please find below script is helpful for you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Are reversal transactions always indicated by a negative value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    m.Date
   , m.Amount
FROM myTable m
    LEFT JOIN myTable m2 on m.Amount = (-1 * m2.Amount)
WHERE m2.Date IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, relying in the amount seems flaky to me but here is a try:

```
SELECT t.date, t.amount
FROM TableName t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableName t1 INNER JOIN TableName t2
                   ON T1.amount  = -t2.amount and T1.date<=t2.date
              WHERE (t.date=t1.date or t.date=t2.date) and t.amount=t1.amount
```

Note that this will not display amounts that appear more than twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for oracle, The Problem with the below query is it reads the main table twice.

```
select Date,Amount from table where amount>0
minus
select Date,-1*amount as Amount from table where amount<0;
```

Comment: Product specific answer (`minus`), to a question with no dbms specified. At least let us know which dbms this is for! (FYI: `EXCEPT` is the ANSI/ISO SQL way.)

Answer (score 0):

based on your Assumed table data using Lag function we can do this

Sample Data :

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (Dates int, Amount int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Dates, Amount)
VALUES
    (01022017, 300),
    (01052017, -300),
    (03042016, 200),
    (06112016, 400),
    (05042016, -200),
    (30012016, 150)
;
```

Script :

```
Select t.Amount from (
select amount,
        coalesce(lag(amount) over (PARTITION BY RIGHT (dates,4) order by (select null)), 0) + amount as diff
from @Table1) T

WHERE  NOT EXISTS (select 1 from @Table1 where T.diff = Amount ) and T.diff <> 0
```